# What is a "Doleiro"?

Tags: significado

I often see in some programs the word *doleiro*, like in News. Usually, they are involved in corruption. But even searching on the internet, I'm not sure if this is a correct definition [(Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doleiro):

> Doleiro é o indivíduo que compra e vende dólares no mercado paralelo. Ao caracterizar alguém como doleiro a Polícia Federal já indicia a ele ao menos nos crimes de lavagem de dinheiro e evasão de divisas. Dessa forma, entende-se que o doleiro é quem converte moedas de um país sem autorização ou além dos limites permitidos das leis vigentes.

Is *doleiro* this? Is this definition correct? Is there any other possible meaning?

<sup>If someone can explain me with "easy words", because I'm not a fluent speaker of portuguese, I would be happy.</sup>

Comment: Don't forget to add a link to your sources.

Comment: Doleiro is a black market dollar dealer.  I just know this from personal experience. At some point, if you've needed to exchange dollars for reais or reais for dollars you might have used one. It is extremely common and used by "respectable" people.

Comment: Yes, the definition is correct.  The clients can vary from big-time criminals to your own mother.

Answer (score 3):

Briefly, **"doleiro"** is the guy who gets your dirty money from crimes or illegal practices here in Brazil and deposits it in offshore tax-havens.

By doing this, the "doleiro" is committing two crimes: "tax evasion" (evasão de divisas), which consists in withdrawing money from one country and depositing it in another country without any formal notification to the competent authorities) and "money laundering": hiding valuable objects resulting from illegal operations.

Because these amounts cannot simply be deposited into the beneficiary's bank account (such a move would raise suspicions), a "Doleiro" seeks a safe destination for the money.

**It is quite common for a "doleiro" to own legal currency exchange offices, which are often used to secretly perform those irregular money operations.** Very rarely can the Internal Revenue Service trace such moves.

I hope I was helpful.

Visit [https://www.nexojornal.com.br/expresso/2016/04/07/O-que-é-um-doleiro-figura-presente-nos-principais-esquemas-de-corrupção](https://www.nexojornal.com.br/expresso/2016/04/07/O-que-%C3%A9-um-doleiro-figura-presente-nos-principais-esquemas-de-corrup%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Comment: This is completely misleading. A doleiro does not get "my" dirty money. The exchange rate they offer is better. Yes, they may have some dirty money customers but many "respectable" people use them. I have used one. And it's on a cash-only basis, too.

Comment: In fact, Brazilians travelling abroad will often use them because the rate is better, and, also, tourists use them (when referred by Brazilians) because the rate is better. Now, there are obviously large transactions carried out re tax havens for the rich etc. but that they also help poorer people, in fact.

Comment: What does "the rate is better" mean? Obviously if the rate is better for someone buying dollars with *reais*, it is worse for those selling dollars for *reais*. Do you mean their spread is smaller? (I don't think so. The advantage of the *doleiro* is rather that s/he doesn't ask for your identity card, which means more privacy and no paperwork.)

Comment: The rate is better means in either direction the exchange rate is better, mostly by getting rid of the bank fees. Exchange rates can be for both directions. SO: when I go to RIO, I take my dollars to the doleiro because he gives me more for my dollars, and when my friends travel ABOARD, they take their reais to them and he will ask for fewer reais per dollar and their money will go farther. Spread is irrelevant, this isn't forex trading. The exchange rates are better regardless of the direction. Why are  you questioning this simple idea??

Comment: @Lambie I guess because the two things you're saying contradict each other. If it's cheaper he's either a) offering a smaller spread or fixed commissions or b) laundering money, at which point setting up worse (for him) exchange rates than what he'd get on the open market would be the price of doing business.

Comment: Being a doleiro is technically illegal but everyone uses them. This: Briefly, "doleiro" is the guy who gets your dirty money from crimes or illegal practices here in Brazil and deposits it in offshore tax-havens." não é necessariamente a verdade. They are just black market dollar dealers. I would avoid the word spread which is a currency **trading term**. Vocês são demais. Credo.

Comment: O clientes podem ser "bandidos" com muita grana, o qualquer pessoa que quer receber mais por menos. "Todo mundo" usa doleiro.

Comment: My experience as a tourist is different from this answer. I would exchange foreign money for local money in the black market, either much more conveniently or sometimes even at a better rate; often even directly to businesses. While this was (strictly speaking) illegal/criminal, it wasn't done as part of some criminal money laundering scheme done by the "service provider" to me. Is this something different from a "doleiro"? The answer could point this out. :)

Comment: @ANeves What you describe is exactly what a black market dollar buyer/seller does. But, they don't do euros, traditionally or other currencies.

Comment: @Lambie I thought we agreed? :) Because yes to what you said, but the "doleiros" weren't getting my "dirty money from crimes or illegal practices [here in Brazil] and deposit[ing] it in offshore tax-havens", they were getting my legally owned and taxed money and converting it (now illegally, yes) to local currency. It might have been a nefarious business for them, but for me it was just a "minor crime" like driving without a driver's license or stealing a towel from the hotel. Thus my comment, similar to yours: I'd love to see the answer updated to include (or exclude) this common-life detail.

Comment: @ANeves My only point was that it's about currency in dollars. That is all I was saying...The fact is the answer is inaccurate;

Comment: Ah, I understand. I didn't mention euros or any other currency, so that's why I misunderstood what you meant to write.

Answer (score 1):

A definição apresentada está correta. Um doleiro é um indivíduo que negocia divisas sem pagar taxas ou impostos. São na verdade muito comuns no Brasil, em alguns Estados mais que em outros, por motivos administrativos e culturais. Geralmente são procurados por oferecerem melhores valores de câmbio.

Under request: English Version

The presented definition is correct. Doleiro is a moneychanger who actively avoids paperwork and taxes. Fairly widespread in Brazil, finding a local doleiro can be much easier in some states than others (e.g. Rio de Janeiro) for a number of reasons. They're popular because of the competitive exchange rates offered.

Comment: Não queres incluir um versão em inglês. Aqui a norma é responder na língua da pergunta.

Comment: Exatamente. É isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

There are *doleiros*, *cambistas* and *remesseiros*. Most people mix them but *doleiro* is as described here some dealing with black money.

*Cambista* is just somebody who exchanges money for you, still as a crime as he doesn't pay IOF and doesn't have legal status to do this.

Remesseiro is someone sending money remittances illegally.

The main difference is, *cambistas* will inlay exchange little money at a lower spread and therefor cheaper prices.

*Remesseiro* may have cheaper prices ans they can send huge amount but most likely not such huge amounts.

*Doleiros* will take huge amounts of dollar from Brazil to a tax heaven or to Paraguay, *doleiros* normally charge much more as this is black money and the person is willing to pay more in order to have the money in a tax heaven.

I live in CDE Paraguay and I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: black money? What's that?